# How to select 10 random images from the MNIST data set without repeating digits (0-9) (Python)

Tags: python, image-processing, mnist, digits

I have this code here

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
num_train_img=x_train.shape[0]
train_ind=np.arange(0,num_train_img)
train_ind_s=np.random.permutation(train_ind)

x_train=x_train[train_ind_s,:,:]
y_train=y_train[train_ind_s]

x_sub=x_train[0:10,:,:]
y_sub=y_train[0:10]
```

This code shuffles the set, then gets the first 10 digits in the set and their labels accordingly (I'm pretty sure. I'm going off some notes but I'm very new to Python and this type of data analysis). Is there a way to make it so that x_sub and y_sub grab the first 10 digits in the set that are not repeating?

For example, if there is an image of a 2, it will be added to the x_sub list, but any later 2s will be skipped over. The list would complete once all digits 0-9 are somewhere in the list.